# How do I get average through ‏multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got homework to get ‏average tags of user in album (`user_id` = x) in the folowing tabels:

```
>>> CREATE TABLE USERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                        NAME TEXT NOT NULL);

>>> CREATE TABLE ALBUMS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                         NAME TEXT NOT NULL, CREATION_DATE TEXT NOT NULL, 
                         USER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) NOT NULL);

>>> CREATE TABLE PICTURES (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                           NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                           LOCATION TEXT NOT NULL,
                           CREATION_DATE TEXT NOT NULL, 
                           ALBUM_ID INTEGER REFERENCES ALBUMS(ALBUM_ID) NOT NULL);

>>> CREATE TABLE TAGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                       PICTURE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES PICTURES(PICTURE_ID) NOT NULL,
                       USER_ID INTEGER REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) NOT NULL);";
```

explenetion: 
Each tag is a row in `TAGS` and it has `picture_id`, each picture has `album_id` and each album has `user_id`, basically i need to count how many times the user is tagged in each album and find the average times that the user is tagged in an album.

I can use this using only: `SELECT ? FROM, AVG(), COUNT(), JOIN (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL JOIN), ON, IN, AND, OR, LIKE, , NOT, (=, != , >, <), IS, DISTINCT, ORDER BY(ASC/DESC), LIMT, OFFSET, and WHERE` that means i cannot use `GROUP BY`

i tried this

```
SELECT * FROM TAGS INNER JOIN PICTURES ON tags.picture_id = PICTURES.Id where album_id IN (select id from ALBUMS where user_id = x) AND user_id = x;
```

but it only gives my a table that has all the tags of the user

How can i get the avg tags per album of (`user_id` = x), is this even possible?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of why you can't use `GROUP BY` would all help.

Comment: What is an *average tag* and how is it calculated?

Comment: It is a homework task

Comment: there is a table name `TAGS` i need to find the average tags per album- each tag has picture id, each picture has album id and each album has user_id, basicly i need to count how many times the user is tagged in each album and find the average the tags per album

Comment: Thanks. That explaination should be added to the question so it's easy to spot, btw. Now... Break it down into smaller steps. Can you come up with a way to count how many times a given user is tagged in a single album? Then in all albums, one row per album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count how many times the user is tagged in each album and then get the average of these counters:

```
select 
  avg(counter) averagetags
from (
  select count(t.user_id) counter
  from albums a 
  inner join pictures p on p.album_id = a.id
  inner join tags t on t.picture_id = p.id
  where t.user_id = ?
  group by a.id
)
```

Comment: Can you do it without using `group by` ?

Comment: With group by you get the number of tags per album. This is the purpose of group by. Then all these numbers are averaged. There is no other  way to obtain these counters.